# SetWindowIcon error: must be in R8G8B8A8 pixel format - raylib c++

Tags: c++, image, raylib

So I am trying to make a window icon for the game and when I load the icon.png image, it says this: `WARNING: GLFW: Window icon image must be in R8G8B8A8 pixel format` and here is my icon: [image: icon] Finally, here is the code snippet:

```
Image icon = LoadImage("pong.png");
SetWindowIcon(icon);
```

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your icon PNG has a bit depth of 24 which means it's missing the alpha channel (the A8 from R8G8B8A8).

Edit the image to save it with the alpha channel. You can check the bit depth in the file properties (should be 32 for RGBA).

Comment: How is it possible to change the bit depth/alpha channel?

Comment: @FunFox Use an editor like Paint, Gimp, Photoshop etc.

Comment: I used GIMP to change it into a 64 bit depth some how so thanks!